# Fast algorithm comparing unsorted data

Tags: python, sql, dna-sequence, genome

I have data that needs to stay in the exact sequence it is entered in (genome sequencing) and I want to search approximately one billion nodes of around 18 members each to locate patterns.

Obviously speed is an issue with this large of a data set, and I actually don't have any data that I can currently use as a discrete key, since the basis of the search is to locate and isolate (but not remove) duplicates.

I'm looking for an algorithm that can go through the data in a relatively short amount of time to locate these patterns and similarities, and I can work out the regex expressions for comparison, but I'm not sure how to get a faster search than O(n).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you concerned only with the search, or loading and reading this data set? That could have a significant impact on the speed of your results.

Comment: We need to be able to display locations of patterns relative to each other to the user based on a potential combination of members.

Comment: O(n) just means you have to look at each node. If they are not organized somehow already, that will be hard to avoid.

Comment: Let me get this straight -- you have one big sequence, and one billion substring queries of ~18 characters each?

Comment: Not quite. I have 9 groups of data sets equaling approximately one billion nodes, which are all relative to each other in a specific sequence. Each node has 18 data points in it. The length of each sequence is about 20 chars, and that's representing one data point inside a single node.

Comment: What's the granularity and maximum length of a pattern? Can it contain partial data points, or must it always start and end on a data point boundary? Can it span multiple data points? Multiple nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- probably what you want is called "de novo assembly"
- an approach would be to calculate N-mers, and use these in an index
- nmers will become more important if you need partial matches / mismatches
- if billion := 1E9, python might be too weak
- also note that 18 bases* 2 bits := 36 bits of information to enumerate them. That is tentavely close to 32 bits and could fit into 64 bits. hashing / bitfiddling *might* be an option